# Cloud Function Crashed getting KeyError "project"

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

Created a cloud function to Enabling real-time email and chat notifications for webex notifications from google support document and function is failing.

```
Error Message in Test Function
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details:
500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Error in traceback
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in    wsgi_app
      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
      rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
      File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site- packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 171, in view_func
      function(data, context)
      File "/workspace/main.py", line 60, in send_webex_teams_notification_2023
      project=asset["resourceProperties"]["project"],
      KeyError: 'project'"
```

I've tried to changed the "project" to project_id,  I tried changing in requirements.txt file to upgrade version of security command center. I also tried changing the security command center link.  I am expecting high or critical errors for all projects in the organization level being monitored and sending specific alerts to webex bot

Code

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import base64
import json

import requests
from google.cloud import securitycenter_v1

WEBEX_TOKEN = "N2YzYjk0NmItNDAxMS00MzdlLWE4MjMtYzFlNGNkNjYxODBmNDZhNWNiOTktOTgx_PF84_e7a300f8-3aac-4db0-9c42-848488a96bf4"
ROOM_ID = "Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNmE1MWEwOTAtYWM3Yy0xMWVkLTkxMDQtYzE1YzVmZDEyMTFi"

TEMPLATE = """
**Severity:** {severity}\n
**Asset:** {asset}\n
**SCC Category:** {category}\n
**Project:** {project}\n
**First observed:** {create_time}\n
**Last observed:** {event_time}\n
**Link to finding:** {finding_link}
```

"""

```
PREFIX = "https://console.cloud.google.com/security/command-center/findings"

def get_finding_detail_page_link(finding_name):
    """Constructs a direct link to the finding detail page."""
    org_id = finding_name.split("/")[1]
    return f"{PREFIX}?organizationId={org_id}&resourceId={finding_name}"

def get_asset(parent, resource_name):
    """Retrieves the asset corresponding to `resource_name` from SCC."""
    client = securitycenter_v1.SecurityCenterClient()
    resp = client.list_assets(
        securitycenter_v1.ListAssetsRequest(
            parent=parent,
            filter=f'securityCenterProperties.resourceName="{resource_name}"',
        )
    )
    page = next(resp.pages)
    if page.total_size == 0:
        return None
    asset = page.list_assets_results[0].asset
    return json.loads(securitycenter_v1.Asset.to_json(asset))

def send_webex_teams_notification(event, context):
    """Send the notification to WebEx Teams."""
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event["data"]).decode("utf-8")
    message_json = json.loads(pubsub_message)
    finding = message_json["finding"]

    parent = "/".join(finding["parent"].split("/")[0:2])
    asset = get_asset(parent, finding["resourceName"])

    requests.post(
        "https://webexapis.com/v1/messages",
        json={
            "roomId": ROOM_ID,
            "markdown": TEMPLATE.format(
                severity=finding["severity"],
                asset=asset["securityCenterProperties"]["resourceDisplayName"],
                category=finding["category"],
                project=asset["resourceProperties"]["project"],
                create_time=finding["createTime"],
                event_time=finding["eventTime"],
                finding_link=get_finding_detail_page_link(finding["name"]),
            ),
        },
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {WEBEX_TOKEN}"},
    )
```

requirements.txt

```
requests==2.25.1
google-cloud-securitycenter==1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a Cloud Functions problem, more so problem with Python.

When you get a key error this is normally due to an attempt to access an item in a dictionary that doesn't exist.

So as we see the error occurs at this line

`project=asset["resourceProperties"]["project"]`

So that means asset['resourceProperties'] does not have a project index.

We can see Asset comes from

```
message_json = json.loads(pubsub_message)
finding = message_json["finding"]
parent = "/".join(finding["parent"].split("/")[0:2])
asset = get_asset(parent, finding["resourceName"])
```

Since there's data being pulled in and joined, it's highly possible the data is nested under something else. Have you outputted the data to see it's structure? Can you display the contents of asset for us and maybe we can help in finding the project index?

Comment: I am a beginner in python so I am not sure how to output the data in python. I used the code directly from google

Comment: @smzj_2023 Not sure if you found the answer. Normally in Python you can do print statements or use a debugger to see data being passed.

So the error happens here project=asset["resourceProperties"]["project"]

You'll want to output asset like 
print(asset) 
You'll then be able to see the structure of it and we can figure out what key values to index by.